# Applications of space filling curves

Tags: reference-request, big-list, orthogonal-polynomials, applications, space-filling-curves

I am seeking articles where a space filling curve has been used as a theoretical application, such as in the study of general orthogonal polynomials.

Comment: The Cannon--Thurston map very naturally associates a space-filling curve to any fibred hyperbolic 3-manifold.

Comment: John Bartholdi III at Georgia Tech has discovered some really cool applications of space-filling curves as heuristics for the travelling salesman problem, which have been applied to a number of real-world problems.  See http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~jjb/research/mow/mow.html and http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~jjb/research/mow/mow.pdf , for example.

Comment: By "*theoretical* application," do you mean to specifically exclude *practical* applications? Among the latter are digital half-toning and nearest-neighbor searching.

Comment: I applied, during the first half of 1985, the Hilbert curve to the image compression.

Answer (score 6):

It's used in Google maps to introduce cache locality: When you move a little bit while viewing the map, you want to be moving only a little bit in the memory, which is after all arranged linearly. This is where *continuous* space filling curves find one of their uses.

**Edit:** You can find a [non-academic references](http://blog.christianperone.com/2015/08/googles-s2-geometry-on-the-sphere-cells-and-hilbert-curve/) about Google's use of Hilbert curves.

Comment: Sounds cool. Can you add a reference so we can read more about it?

Comment: That seems to imply if you happen to be in the wrong part of the map, like near $(1/2,1)$ for the Hilbert curve illustrated on Wikipedia, you have a massive jump in memory location.

Comment: @AHusain, one does the best. It's never going to be perfect.

Answer (score 5):

In a very different style, N. Katz has studied "space filling curves" over finite fields (https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nmk/spacefill.pdf), and given some applications (e.g., every abelian variety over a finite field is a quotient of the jacobian of a curve, using ideas of Gabber).

Answer (score 5):

Space filling curves have been used a good deal by Katsuya Eda and his coauthors to compute singular homology groups of Peano continua (which are precisely the continuous images of $[0,1]$).

For example:

The singular homology of the Griffiths Twin cone is computed in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0567v1.pdf). A key part of this is Theorem 3.1 which requires the use of a space filling curve.

Similar techniques are used in

K. Eda, K. Kawamura, *[The surjectivity of the canonical homomorphism from singular homology to Cech homology](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2000-128-05/S0002-9939-99-05670-1/)*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 128 (1999), 1487–1495. (See Lemma 2.4)

K. Eda, *[Singular homology groups of one-dimensional Peano continua](http://www.logic.info.waseda.ac.jp/~eda/pdf/singular.pdf)*
 (see Lemma 4.1)

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in signal processing, it seems that space filling curves are widely used there; see [this article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=908985) and [this one.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=122727)

It would be most helpful if you narrow down the field of application, or instead ask for a "big-list" of all possible applications.

Answer (score 3):

In a similar manner to the way they are used by Google maps, space filling curves are used for load balancing super computers. Since computational domains are sometimes more refined in certain locations, space filling curves can catch this (by refining the curve as needed). Another advantage of using these curves for load balancing is that communication between computation units is usually better (though this is only a heuristic).